# MongoDB - Unable to update array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi Can some one explain what's wrong with my controller code?I am trying to modify an item  present in an array using the controller code.It neither gives error nor update my db

Model

```
 var localTransportSchema = new Schema({

                name: { type: String, required: false, trim: true },
                contact: {
                    addressLine1: { type: String, required: false },        
                    serviceActiveFlag: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N'] },
            }, 
            vehicle: [{
                vehicleType:{ type: String, required: false, enum: ['sedan', 'hatchback', 'suv', 'mpv', 'luxury'] },
                activeFlag:{type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N']}        
            }]
        });
        module.exports.transportModel = mongoose.model(collection, localTransportSchema);
```

Controller

```
transportModel.findOne({ "name": req.body['providerName'], "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']), "vehicle": { $elemMatch: { "vehicleType": req.body['vehicleType'] } } },
             function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record : - " + err.message);
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " in transport details table"
                    }));
                } else if (doc === null) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details : - unable to update database");
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " due to " + err.message
                    }));
                } else {

                    doc.set({                        
                        "vehicle.$.activeFlag": req.body['vehicleActiveFlag']
                    })
                    //save document
                    doc.save()
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a method `findOneAndUpdate` which return updated document:

```
transportModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": req.body['providerName'], "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']), "vehicle": { $elemMatch: { "vehicleType": req.body['vehicleType'] } } }, {$set: {"vehicle.$.activeFlag": req.body['vehicleActiveFlag']}}, {new: true},
             function (err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record : - " + err.message);
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " in transport details table"
                    }));
                } else if (doc === null) {
                    logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details : - unable to update database");
                    return reject(res.status(409).json({
                        "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " due to " + err.message
                    }));
                } else {
                      console.log(doc);
                      res.status(200).json(doc); 
                  }

            });
```

Comment: awesome.Thanks for your help